# Sections of overlapping Circles

Tags: geometry

3 part question here. In terms of n, what is the maximum amount of regions that can be made by overlapping n circles? Does circle size count? Do both of the answers to the previous questions correlate with regular polygons as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "sections" ? Arcs or regions ?

Comment: Meaning regions, sorry if that was unclear

Comment: The reference I just gave deals with your first question.  I think that, if you have thick borders, the answer to your second question is clearly "at most the answer of Question 1". Regarding your last question about (regular ?) polygons, I think that you have to treat separately overlapping (equilateral) triangles, overlapping squares, etc... I do not have references for that.